# How should I encode player position for input into a nueral network

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network

I have a simple grid based game on an 8x8 grid that I am training a neural network on, however I am not sure what the best way to represent the player's position is.
My current ideas are:
-Have one input equal to the x position + 8*(y position)
-Have two inputs for the x and y position
-Have 64 inputs, set to 1 if they match the position and 0 otherwise
Which of these is the best, or is there a better way to represent it?

Comment: This question is likely better suited for [AI SE](https://ai.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

It'll be best to use a separate input for each possible position.

If your game doesn't have any "directional rules", though, then you can first rotate the board so that the player is in the top-left quadrant.  That reduces the number of inputs you need from 64 to 16.

Then, if it doesn't affect the rules of the game, flip the board diagonally, or not, so that the player is closer to the top than the left.  That reduces the number of inputs you need from 16 to 10.